# Error in my Fragment Class missing return statement

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is  my YoutubeFragment.java

```
public class YoutubeFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String[] YOUTUBE_PLAYLISTS = {
            "PLpzzpBegb_9o6SkHEMbF5bcQYzxOARrAY",
            "PLWz5rJ2EKKc_Tt7q77qwyKRgytF1RzRx8",
    };
    private YouTube mYoutubeDataApi;
    private final GsonFactory mJsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
    private final HttpTransport mTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    View myView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_activity, container, false);


        if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(getActivity().getApplicationContext())){
            return myView;
        }else showNetDisabledAlertToUser(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } //error here 
}
```

Getting error at second last '}' syaing missing return satement. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return your View below

```
if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(getActivity()))
{ // Do your work

}else 
  { showNetDisabledAlertToUser(getActivity());    
  }

return myView;
```

**FYI**

Why you calling

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

You should call [**getActivity()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) here .

Comment: Getting error android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:575)
                                                                   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)

Comment: I didnt downvote; but answering a low quality question is always risky. You started up with just some code thrown at people, without **any** piece of explanation. And it is not like you added much of explanation. Are you really that surprised that such answers dont fly?

Comment: @GhostCat indeed . I will obey your comments .

Comment: I'm really sorry for posting such low quality question Mr Android God. I should have know

Comment: @Paperwrk No problem .Move ahead

Comment: I would suggest "doing your stuff" instead. "Doing your staff" will probably not make you emplyee of the month :).

Answer (score 0):

```
else showNetDisabledAlertToUser(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Is the second path in your method. There first one is "if/then" but when that if is not taken; "if/else" kicks. And then ... there is no return statement on that path! And that is what the compiler is telling you.

The **real** lesson here: if you don't understand such super-basic problems of java, then you should **stop** doing android work for a while. Instead: work on those java basics. You better focus on learning to crawl before trying to run!